# Can I put four outlets on each of two 20A circuits in my garage?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I turned my garage into a woodworking shop. I currently have a single 20a circuit in the garage and I want to add more using the same 3/4 EMT conduit. I've installed 240a circuit so I feel comfortable doing this myself.

I was wondering if I add two additional 20a circuit with 12 gauge wire, can I add four outlets on each circuit (two outlets on a 2-gang box)? Total I will have eight outlets (four for each circuit) and total four 2-gang boxes. Since all  circuit will be sharing the same 3/4 EMT conduit going in the same direction/run, can I use the current ground wire and add onto it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no code limit for how many receptacles on a circuit.

One ground wire sized for the largest circuit is good, but with EMT no ground wire is necessary at all.